# How to update specific value in mongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have to update password field against specific email-id .

When run this query :

`db.user_account.update({"password":"1233465"},{$set:{"password": "1233"}}`

it will update every password value in `user_account` (collections) but i want to filter collection based on email-id then on a specific email-id i want update old password with new password using python....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter of [`update`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) is the filtering query. Assuming you use `pymongo`:

`db.user_account.update({"email-id": "specific"}, {"$set": {"password": "1233"}})`

Comment: Notet that you can also verify the user's password and atomically update it if it matches, by including the old password in the filtering query, e.g. `{"email-id": "specific", "password": "oldPassword"}`.  As a sidenote: don't store plaintext passwords in your database; use a standardized password hashing scheme instead.